# Python process thread start and stop timer

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm having problems with my code and I'm not sure why python is not calling my function.

Here is the code I have. I only get Done to print out vice the print statements in **startProcess**

```
def startProcess(self):
    print("hello")

def repeat(self):
    self.startProcess
    print("Done")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually [*calling*](http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) `self.startProcess`, or is it a typo?

Try:

```
self.startProcess()
```

Comment: I tired it and it worked... so simple Thanks

Comment: @John, I'm just guessing, but you probably programmed in a language before, that hides the distinction between attributes and function calls, e.g. Ruby?